# User to execute a scheduled function they don't have access to

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, triggers

Can a user successfully execute a scheduled trigger for a custom function without having view/edit access to the apps script project that hosts the function this scheduled trigger is calling?

Right now, a user is able to schedule a trigger, but the function fails to execute. If the same user is given at least view access to the apps script project, the function executes successfully.

Is there a way to make that trigger initiated function executable without actually having view/edit access to the code? That function needs to execute as the user scheduling the trigger.

Comment: I don't think so because as you can see in the both editors that access to the trigger dialog is given to users that have access to the editor.  So in order to be able to create and authorize a trigger to  a function requires edit access.  I believe that the only way for this to circumvent this is to deploy the script as an addon.

Comment: Hi there @OctopusPete! I strongly suggest you to take the approach commented by @Cooper and write back to us with your findings.